# Can I give the client the permissions to control the data on FireBase himself?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm now working with flutter and firebase and I want to start freelancing. But when I create a project in firebase the project gets saved on my own account, So can I make the client able to control data himself?

Comment: welcome to SO, you can ask these types of question of stack exchange. Well, you can transfer the project to client's google account. or ask him to create a project and give the access of it as admin.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to `Users and Permissions`:

[image]

And add him to the project. Even with `owner` role:

[image]

It would also work the other side around. If the user want's to create the project on his own he could give you this kind of access.